# Chrome flag for --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

How can we set the following flag in Google Chrome for android?

```
--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="example.com"
```

(replacing "example.com" with the origin you actually want to test)

Comment: Older method for setting arbitrary flags: [Run google-chrome with flags on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280796/run-google-chrome-with-flags-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

This was added to the `chrome://flags` page in 2018. See `chrome://flags#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` for a textbox that allows you to supply the list.

Comment: Landed in Chrome 68, specifically.