# How to solve no conscrypt_openjdk_jni in java.library.path error?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, apk, linker-errors, sign

I want to sign my apk, so I executed the following command:

> java -jar signapk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 app-debug.apk
>   ~/Desktop/test.apk

but I got the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   conscrypt_openjdk_jni in java.library.path    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)    at
>   org.conscrypt.NativeCryptoJni.init(NativeCryptoJni.java:25)   at
>   org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.(NativeCrypto.java:54)     at
>   org.conscrypt.OpenSSLBIOInputStream.(OpenSSLBIOInputStream.java:34)
>     at
>   org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.fromX509PemInputStream(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:119)
>     at
>   org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$1.fromX509PemInputStream(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:220)
>     at
>   org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$1.fromX509PemInputStream(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:216)
>     at
>   org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$Parser.generateItem(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:94)
>     at
>   org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.engineGenerateCertificate(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:272)
>     at
>   java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
>     at com.android.signapk.SignApk.readPublicKey(SignApk.java:182)  at
>   com.android.signapk.SignApk.main(SignApk.java:1087)

How to solve this error?

(openjdk version "1.8.0_141"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-8u141-b15-3~14.04-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)
)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
java -Xmx2048m -Djava.library.path="out/host/linux-x86/lib64" \
    -jar out/host/linux-x86/framework/signapk.jar \
    -w build/target/product/security/platform.x509.pem \
    build/target/product/security/platform.pk8 \
    FileNeedSign.apk FileNeedSign_Signed.apk
```

Comment: Even though this is the accepted answer to be more helpful please add description to your answer and the reason why additional arguments had fixed the issue

Comment: To find out your java.library.path, type this in your cmd `java -XshowSettings:properties` (Scroll up to find your library path, it will show help options too when you use that command)

Comment: didn't help for Windows10:  still `no conscrypt_openjdk_jni-windows-x86_64 in java.library.path`

Comment: Me too didn't help for Windows10: still no conscrypt_openjdk_jni-windows-x86_64 in java.library.path

Comment: Worked for me on Linux with -Djava.library.path="sdk/tools/linux/lib64"
but only after I cloned the Android SDK repo with:
`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/sdk`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Jetty, Kotlin, Java 8, and Maven.  My solution was twofold.  First in pom.xml, add Conscrypt:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.conscrypt</groupId>
    <artifactId>conscrypt-openjdk</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Note the `<classifier>` which needs to be right for your operating system.  Pick one from the list here: https://github.com/google/conscrypt/

I like to put my configuration right in the code.  Flame me if you like.  I followed the instructions here: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html#conscrypt So right before setting up Jetty's sslContextFactory, I had to add:

```kotlin
    Security.addProvider(new OpenSSLProvider())
```

then after:

```kotlin
    // SSLv2Hello and SSLv3 are outdated and insecure.
    // TLSv1.3 works with Conscrypt, but not Java 8!
    sslContextFactory.setExcludeProtocols("SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3", "TLSv1.3")
    sslContextFactory.setProvider("Conscrypt");
```

I think that's what cleared it up.  I made a lot of changes today.

I had a separate issue which was that my localhost SSL certificate was invalid.  I started with this: [Can you use a service worker with a self-signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728176/can-you-use-a-service-worker-with-a-self-signed-certificate) but ended up grabbing a cert from a server and editing my /etc/hosts file to make localhost look like that server.