# GCP PubSub - Java - Unix native library issues

Tags: unix, google-cloud-platform

##### Environment details

OS type and version: `Linux 3.0.101-108.108-default x86_64 Java version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)`

##### Steps to reproduce

1. It's a simple subscriber taken from [GCP GitLab](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries).
2. The Unix box where ever I am deploying, I shouldn't be installing or changing any softwares on it, just copy the spring boot jar and run the app. It should work as is.

##### Any additional information below

The same Spring boot executable jar works perfectly fine on Windows, but if I run the same jar on Unix environment throws this error. I have used the maven dependencies of netty and other native libraries as shown in the code below. Still throws the same error.

```bash
rpm -qa | fgrep glibc
glibc-32bit-2.11.3-17.110.33.1
glibc-2.11.3-17.110.33.1
glibc-devel-2.11.3-17.110.33.1
glibc-locale-32bit-2.11.3-17.110.33.1
glibc-locale-2.11.3-17.110.33.1
glibc-devel-32bit-2.11.3-17.110.33.1
glibc-i18ndata-2.11.3-17.110.33.1
```

**Observation**

I suspect I need to downgrade my GCP library version to make GLIBC version compatible, with the current GCP versions what ever I am using in `pom.xml`, I see below errors in logs (complete stacktrace is shown at the bottom):

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libconscrypt_openjdk_jni-linux-x86_6416587725916100000.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `**GLIBC_2.14**' not found (required by /tmp/libconscrypt_openjdk_jni-linux-x86_6416587725916100000.so)

##### Code

```java
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.AckReplyConsumer;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ProjectSubscriptionName;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

@Component
public class PackageGcpSubscriber {

    public PackageGcpSubscriber(){
        subscription("ph-package-lwr", "package_file_core_dev_sub");
    }

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PackageGcpSubscriber.class);

    public List<String> subscription(String projectId, String subscriptionId) {
        ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName =
                ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId);
        List<String> packageList = new ArrayList<>();
        Subscriber subscriber = null;
        try {

            subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName,
                    (PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) -> {
                        String subData = message.getData().toStringUtf8();
                        logger.info("Data ::"+subData);
                        consumer.ack();
                    }).build();
            subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
            logger.info("Listening for messages on {}:", subscriptionName);
            subscriber.awaitTerminated(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException timeoutException) {
            subscriber.stopAsync();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ///
        }
        return packageList;
    }
}
```

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>3.2.1</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.alpn</groupId>
            <artifactId>alpn-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3.v20160715</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.54.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

##### Stack trace

```java
2022-07-25 14:09:48.027  INFO 25803 --- [           main] com.my.packa.PubSubApp               : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-07-25 14:09:51.651  INFO 25803 --- [           main] i.g.n.s.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts    : Java 9 ALPN API unavailable (this may be normal)
2022-07-25 14:09:51.664  INFO 25803 --- [           main] i.g.n.s.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts    : netty-tcnative unavailable (this may be normal)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64, netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_fedora, netty_tcnative_x86_64, netty_tcnative]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:107) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:705) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[packa-pubsub-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[packa-pubsub-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[packa-pubsub-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_x86_646976970630165030878.so: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.12' not found (required by /tmp/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_x86_646976970630165030878.so)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:36) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:319) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:196) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:98) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
                ... 55 common frames omitted
                Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_x86_646976970630165030878.so: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.12' not found (required by /tmp/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_x86_646976970630165030878.so)
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
                        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
                        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
                      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:345)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:311)
                        ... 57 common frames omitted
                Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64 in java.library.path
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:319)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:139)
                        ... 56 common frames omitted
                        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64 in java.library.path
                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                 at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:345)
                                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:311)
                                ... 57 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_fedora
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:217) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:98) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
                ... 55 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_fedora.so
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:164)
                ... 56 common frames omitted
                Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_fedora in java.library.path
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:319)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:139)
                        ... 56 common frames omitted
                        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_fedora in java.library.path
                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                               at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:345)
                                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:311)
                                ... 57 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_x86_64
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:217) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:98) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
                ... 55 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_x86_64.so
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:164)
                ... 56 common frames omitted
                Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_x86_64 in java.library.path
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:319)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:139)
                        ... 56 common frames omitted
                        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_x86_64 in java.library.path
                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                 at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:345)
                                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:311)
                                ... 57 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:217) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:98) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
                ... 55 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative.so
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:164)
                ... 56 common frames omitted
                Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative in java.library.path
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:319)
                        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:139)
                        ... 56 common frames omitted
                        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative in java.library.path
                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
                                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:353)
                                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:345)
                                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:311)
                                ... 57 common frames omitted

2022-07-25 14:09:51.673  INFO 25803 --- [           main] i.g.n.s.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts    : Conscrypt not found (this may be normal)

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at io.grpc.internal.ConscryptLoader.newProvider(ConscryptLoader.java:78) ~[grpc-core-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts$ConscryptHolder.<clinit>(GrpcSslContexts.java:295) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.findJdkProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:268) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:234) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:146) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:95) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$DefaultProtocolNegotiator.newNegotiator(NettyChannelBuilder.java:628) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[packa-pubsub-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[packa-pubsub-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[packa-pubsub-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[packa-pubsub-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libconscrypt_openjdk_jni-linux-x86_6416587725916100000.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /tmp/libconscrypt_openjdk_jni-linux-x86_6416587725916100000.so)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:106) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.conscrypt.NativeCryptoJni.init(NativeCryptoJni.java:50) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.<clinit>(NativeCrypto.java:64) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.conscrypt.Conscrypt.checkAvailability(Conscrypt.java:119) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        at org.conscrypt.Conscrypt.newProvider(Conscrypt.java:133) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
        ... 60 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libconscrypt_openjdk_jni-linux-x86_6416587725916100000.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /tmp/libconscrypt_openjdk_jni-linux-x86_6416587725916100000.so)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:52) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromCurrentClassloader(NativeLibraryLoader.java:318) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:273) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                ... 67 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no conscrypt_openjdk_jni-linux-x86_64 in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:54) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                ... 66 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no conscrypt_openjdk_jni-linux-x86_64 in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:54) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromCurrentClassloader(NativeLibraryLoader.java:318) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:273) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                ... 66 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no conscrypt_openjdk_jni in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:54) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromHelperClassloader(NativeLibraryLoader.java:289) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:262) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                ... 66 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no conscrypt_openjdk_jni in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:54) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromCurrentClassloader(NativeLibraryLoader.java:318) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:273) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                ... 66 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no conscrypt in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:54) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:262) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                ... 66 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no conscrypt in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:54) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromCurrentClassloader(NativeLibraryLoader.java:318) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                at org.conscrypt.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:273) ~[conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.5.1.jar!/:2.5.1]
                ... 66 common frames omitted

2022-07-25 14:09:51.677  INFO 25803 --- [           main] i.g.n.s.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts    : Jetty ALPN unavailable (this may be normal)

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.JettyTlsUtil.isJettyAlpnConfigured(JettyTlsUtil.java:64) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.findJdkProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:254) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:234) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:146) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.45.0.jar!/:1.45.0]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your actual issue might be different. The messages are at INFO level and there are messages in parens "(this may be normal)". If you suppress debug logs what error do you see?

Comment: Have you configured your Java environment to work with GCP projects as follows in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/setup#optional_install_maven_or_gradle_plugin_for_app_engine)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a kernel which was built against `GLIBC_2.14` or `GLIBC_2.12` - `GLIBC_2.11` is too old.

It not only complains about `GLIBC_2.14`:

> `UnsatisfiedLinkError`: /tmp/libconscrypt_openjdk_jni-linux-x86_6416587725916100000.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /tmp/libconscrypt_openjdk_jni-linux-x86_6416587725916100000.so)

But it also complains about `GLIBC_2.12`:

> `UnsatisfiedLinkError`: /tmp/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_x86_646976970630165030878.so: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.12' not found (required by /tmp/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_x86_646976970630165030878.so

You need to use both versions, which need the same `GLIBC` requirement as the kernel's `GLIBC` version offers. So you need a kernel with `GLIBC_2.14` or `GLIBC_2.12` to begin with. Mixing these versions is definitely not possible. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451371/how-to-solve-no-conscrypt-openjdk-jni-in-java-library-path-error) seems similar, but there may be two version issues.