# Service worker with self signed certificate on Android WebView

Tags: android, certificate, android-webview, service-worker

Is it possible to use service worker with self-signed certificates?

I know that it is possible on the desktop using the flag `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=` at the start (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43484456).

But how can I achieve this on Android `WebView`?

I've already created a custom `WebViewClient` to skip all the SSL errors:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed();
}
```

but this does not seem to help here.

Comment: No solution? ping

Answer (score -1):

**This will cause the app to always accept untrusted certs.**

```
public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        if ( SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED == error.getPrimaryError() ){
            handler.proceed();
        } else {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        }
    }
```

Better solution is use your [certicate](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#UnknownCa)

```
String sslCertificate = error.getCertificate().toString();
    String mySslCertificate = new SslCertificate(cert).toString(); //cert is stored inside /raw 
    if ( sslCertificate.equals(mySslCertificate) )
        handler.proceed();
```

Comment: Hi, I already trust all certificates, as you can see in my question.