# Hosting a blazor web app without ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, iis, blazor

I have made a web app using Blazor and now i want to host in my server with a free .ml domain. But service-worker.js not running without a secure connection. It is a free domain so i don't want to pay for a certificate.

Use SSL option in the project property is unchecked in all projects. 
I couldn't find any information about this online.
Can i force to use http ?

Thanks

[SSL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af4T6.jpg)

Comment: With so many free certificate options (like Let's Encrypt), I wonder why you still have such questions.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know that could be a free ssl option. Thank's i've managed to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Service worker requires https except the localhost to work. Both the third-party certificate and the self-signed certificate is ok as long as we established the certificate trust relationship between the client-side and the server-side properly(for exchanging the public key of certificate).
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/
For free SSL certificate,
https://geekflare.com/free-ssl-tls-certificate/
For self-signed certificate,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps
Here is an example of using a self-signed certificate.
[Can you use a service worker with a self-signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728176/can-you-use-a-service-worker-with-a-self-signed-certificate)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

To use HTTP in a Blazor app, in Program.cs remove UseHsts() and
UseHttpsRedirection() if present:

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for 
    production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    // app.UseHsts();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

In launchSettings.json make sure there is only an HTTP URL:

```
"profiles": {
    "Dashboard": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": true,
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "applicationUrl": "http://10.72.11.110:5238",
    "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
},
```