.Net 8 Blazor WASM PWA Install button shows locally and disappear when published
The current Blazro WASM application was created as PWA. When I run it locally during the development the install app icon shows normally

When I publish the application on IIS or change the application URL in launchSettings.json file, the Install icon disapeare.

Install icon shows

"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7244;"


Install icon disappear (192.168.1.100 is my local machine IP)

"applicationUrl": "https://192.168.1.100:7244;"

According to THIS document all the needed PWA configuration is done .. Any help
Thanks in advance

Is you SSL certificate a self-sign that you need to accept the risk before logging on to? That might be an issue for the PWA.

I added Self-Signed certificate in IIS and assigned it to my web app .. same issue

I meant is that browsers are really strict with SSL certificate, if you use a self-sign certificate, they might not allow PWA. If you accept the risk once a week for your self-sign this might not be allowed. Maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728176/can-you-use-a-service-worker-with-a-self-signed-certificate


When I publish the application on IIS or change the application URL in launchSettings.json file, the Install icon disapeare.

The reason of this problem is the security restrictions imposed by the browser.
By default, browsers do not allow local files to be installed as applications due to security concerns. When you publish the application to IIS, the browser treats it as a local file and Install icon will be hided.
Usually, there are two solutions to this issue.
Use a Self-Signed Certificate

Create a self-signed certificate.
install the certificate into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store. This will allow the browser to treat the application as a trusted source and display the Install icon. You may forget this step.
Publish the application to IIS using the self-signed certificate.

Use a Local HTTPS Development Server

Install the .NET Core SDK and create a new Blazor WebAssembly application.
Use HTTPS Redirection Middleware to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS or Use HSTS Middleware to send HTTP Strict Transport Security Protocol (HSTS) headers to clients.
Trust the development certificate and access the application using HTTPS.

The more detailed information you can refer to this document.
