# Android how to set --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com" flag

Tags: android, google-chrome

Please someone tell me how to get this flag working because I have tried a lot of things but none of those things worked. Firstly, I tried using the about:flags in google chrome but that seems to not work, because everytime I type the website inside it, it doesn't show when I restart.Secondly, I tried using adb shell but I dont know how that thing works, so I tried using this command :
`echo "chrome --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com" " > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line` and it said that the folder is not existing Lastly, I tried to turn in about:flags the console command flag and than, when I typed the adress inside the unsafe flag it showed, but when I tried to access the website it still shows as insecure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run google-chrome with flags on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280796/run-google-chrome-with-flags-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins this flag requires root access on the device; it recommends setting up [Chrome port forwarding](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server) instead.